# Twisted+GTK app becomes unresponsive while downloading files

Tags: gtk, twisted, pygtk

I'd like to use Twisted and GTK+ in the same application.  I'm using the gtk2reactor, made all my code properly non-blocking, and generally it works pretty well.

However, when I have a (HTTP) download running, the GUI becomes unresponsive and laggy.  It is as if something in twisted blocks (for very short time periods) and the reactor doesn't process GTK events often enough.  Basically, I'm using:

```
factory = twc.HTTPDownloader(url, filename)
reactor.connectTCP(host, port, factory)
```

Here is a [little PyGtk program](https://gist.github.com/jdmansour/5280273) to demonstrate the problem.  I only have a dummy progress bar there to show some animation, but the problem is also noticeable in a full-blown program. There is a noticeable lag when scrolling, or switching between GtkNotebook tabs, as long as a download is running.

Is this expected, or am I doing something wrong? I've done a GTK + Twisted application before and have never noticed this, but then I also have never transfered larger files (~300 MB) before in twisted. Maybe twisted chooses too big a chunk size and stays busy for too long (~100ms?) before giving control back to the main loop? Should I be using separate threads for the GTK and twisted loops instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I give you any advice about fixing this problem, I should note that whenever faced with a performance issue like this, you should profile your application to see what is taking the most time.  You can use a profiler like [`cProfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile); or perhaps [statprof](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statprof/), or perhaps [this cool hack from Geoff Greer](http://geoff.greer.fm/2012/02/04/my-twisted-hack-day-project-why-is-the-reactor-pausing/) that is specifically for figuring out what's blocking Twisted's reactor.  Objective data is always better than conjecture, and your specific data can only be obtained from your specific environment.

That said, I do have some conjecture for you.  Most likely the problem here is the file I/O.  Non-blocking file I/O is a bit of a sore spot for Twisted, because [it is basically impossible to do](http://neugierig.org/software/blog/2011/12/nonblocking-disk-io.html) without just spinning up a thread, so it's not clear how to structure a portable API that would eventually suit a future platform-specific API.  Nevertheless, Twisted *ought* to have something that abstracts away the threading part of this for you.

`HTTPDownloader`, specifically, does [blocking file writes](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/web/client.py#L506) which will make the reactor get stuck and your GUI freeze up.  You can override `pagePart` to do something non-blocking; however, this then means that you need to do [flow-control](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/producers.html) on the `HTTPPageDownloader` object's `transport` attribute - e.g. tell it to `pauseProducing` - or you might end up buffering all ~300MB of that file in memory if you have a slow disk.

You might find all of this easier if you use the new `Agent` API.  You still need to do your own non-blocking file I/O, but at least the [`deliverBody`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html#auto4) API will give you a `transport` object conveniently accessible with a `pauseProducing` method you can call directly instead of subclassing several different things and wading through several layers of abstraction (`ClientFactory`, `HTTPClientFactory`, `HTTPDownloader`, `HTTPPageDownloader`) to get access to it.

I realize that flow-control ought to be easier to manage in Twisted, and I'm sorry that this is a bit fiddly to set up.  I know, and [we're working on it.](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/1956)

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, all the links were very helpful! For now, I put all the gui stuff in a separate thread, since I have no experience with flow-control. It works better now, although I no longer have twisted's benefit of having all code on one thread. Also I'm a bit worried that the HTTP downloader's IO might starve other things going on in my reactor later on, but so far so good.

Comment: GTK does not work well with multiple threads.  Depending on how you did this, you may experience strange behavior or crashes.  Definitely you should no longer be using the GTK reactor if you have moved the Twisted loop to another thread.